# Laravel is it correct to put business logic in Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and I do not quite understand where to put my business logic. At this point, I put the business logic in a model or service (depending on size), so my controllers can be as thin as possible. Is my approach correct? I saw several examples of models in which there were only relationships, but in this case where to store business logic?

Here's examples of my model and service
Model

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','category_id','difficulty','max_time','questions','max_points'];

   public function questions() // questions with answers related to chosen test
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Question::class)->inRandomOrder();
   }

    public function testCategories() // full info about every available category
    {
        return $this->with('category')
            ->select('category_id',
                DB::raw('min(difficulty) as minDifficulty'),
                DB::raw('max(difficulty) as maxDifficulty'),
                DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('category_id')
            ->get();
    }
    public function category()  // info about chosen tests category
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
    }

    public function categoryTests($id,$testName = null)  // list of tests in chosen category
    {
        if(is_null($testName)) {
            return $this->with('category')
                ->where('category_id', $id)
                ->get();
        } else {
            return $this->with('category')
                ->where('name','like','%' . $testName . '%')
                ->get()
                ->sortBy('category_id');
        }
    }

    public function getTestData($id)  // get questions with answers + category
    {
        return $this->with(['questions.answers','category'])->where('id',$id)->get();
    }

    public function users()   // pivot table
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_test');
    }



// Admin Section

    public function getAdminTestData($data)
    {
        return $this->with(['questionsCount','category'])
            ->where('id',($id ?? '!='),($id ?? 'null'))
            ->orderBy($data['orderBy'] ?? 'id',$data['param'] ?? 'asc')
            ->paginate(15);
    }


    public function questionsCount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class)
            ->select('id','test_id',DB::raw('count(test_id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('test_id');

    }

    public function saveTest($data)
    {
       return $this->create([
            'name' => $data['testName'],
            'description' => $data['testDescription'],
            'category_id'=> $data['testCategory'],
            'difficulty' => $data['testDifficulty'],
            'max_time' => $data['maxTime'],
            'questions' => $data['questionsCount'],
            'max_points' => $data['max_points']
        ]);
    }

    public function getTestInfo($id)
    {
       return $this->with('getQuestionsInfo')->where('id',$id)->first();
    }

    public function updateTest($id,$data)
    {
        $this->find($id)->update([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'category_id' => $data['category_id'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'max_time' => $data['max_time'],
            'difficulty' => $data['difficulty'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getQuestionsInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class)->with(['answersCount']);
    }
}
```

Service

```
  public function handleTestCreate(Request $request) : void
    {
        $data =  $request->json()->all();
        $id = $this->model->saveTest($data)->id;
        foreach ($data['questions'] as $question) {
            $questionId = Question::create([
                'question_body' => $question['name'],
                'test_id' => $id,
                'points' => $question['points']
            ])->id;
            foreach ($question['answers'] as $answer) {
                Answer::create([
                    'answer_body' => $answer['name'],
                    'question_id' => $questionId,
                    'is_correct' => $answer['correct']
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it comes down to handling a more complex way of creating, updating etc. of models have a look into repositories.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You approach is quite opposite of what is recommended. Controllers should handle the interaction between your view and model. A model should only have details related to the model such as relationships and the same applies to the views.

Intro to MVC framework: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm

Personally, I would have 3 controllers for Questions, Categories and Admin as well as the Model like so:

**Test.php**

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','description','category_id','difficulty','max_time','questions','max_points'];

    public function category()  // info about chosen tests category
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
    }

    public function users()   // pivot table
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_test');
    }

    public function getQuestionsInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class)->with(['answersCount']);
    }
}
```

**QuestionController.php**

```
use App\Test; // Import Model in Controller

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class QuestionsController extends Controller
{
    public function questions() // questions with answers related to chosen test
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class)->inRandomOrder();
    }

    public function getTestData($id)  // get questions with answers + category
    {
        return Test::with(['questions.answers','category'])->where('id',$id)->get();
    }
}
```

**CategoriesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function testCategories() // full info about every available category    {
        return $this->with('category')
            ->select('category_id',
                DB::raw('min(difficulty) as minDifficulty'),
                DB::raw('max(difficulty) as maxDifficulty'),
                DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('category_id')
            ->get();
    }

    public function categoryTests($id,$testName = null)  // list of tests in chosen category
    {
        if(is_null($testName)) {
            return $this->with('category')
                ->where('category_id', $id)
                ->get();
        } else {
            return $this->with('category')
                ->where('name','like','%' . $testName . '%')
                ->get()
                ->sortBy('category_id');
        }
    }

}
```

**Admin Controller**

```
<?php

use App\Test; // Import Model in Controller

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function getAdminTestData($data)
    {
        return Test::with(['questionsCount','category'])
            ->where('id',($id ?? '!='),($id ?? 'null'))
            ->orderBy($data['orderBy'] ?? 'id',$data['param'] ?? 'asc')
            ->paginate(15);
    }


    public function questionsCount()
    {
        return Test::hasMany(Question::class)
            ->select('id','test_id',DB::raw('count(test_id) as total'))
            ->groupBy('test_id');
    }

    public function saveTest($data)
    {
       return Test::create([
            'name' => $data['testName'],
            'description' => $data['testDescription'],
            'category_id'=> $data['testCategory'],
            'difficulty' => $data['testDifficulty'],
            'max_time' => $data['maxTime'],
            'questions' => $data['questionsCount'],
            'max_points' => $data['max_points']
        ]);
    }

    public function getTestInfo($id)
    {
       return Test::with('getQuestionsInfo')->where('id',$id)->first();
    }

    public function updateTest($id,$data)
    {
        Test::find($id)->update([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'category_id' => $data['category_id'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'max_time' => $data['max_time'],
            'difficulty' => $data['difficulty'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Code is not guaranteed as there might be syntax or logical error but the structure is what I'm trying to get across.

Answer (score 0):

@tereško you are correct, You cant write queries in your controllers its a bad practise, here is a good read that will help, as said business logic must be in your controllers
https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices

Comment: here is another link, I know its a Old post but if some stumbles on it, then its a bonus https://luis-barros-nobrega.medium.com/laravel-how-to-move-fat-logic-to-the-model-layer-e2e3bfa2240

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31934544)